# Rails : can't convert Regexp into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following code in my rails controller:

```
@main_mastertest = $connection.execute("SELECT * FROM builds;")

@l2_tmp_mastertest = Array.new
@l2_tmp_mastertest = @main_mastertest.map {|y|[y[0]]}

@l2_mastertest = Array.new
@l2_mastertest = @l2_tmp_mastertest.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element|
hash[element] +=1
hash }

@l2_mastertest = @l2_mastertest.sort_by { |x, _| x }.reverse
```

After that I try to do something like this in my view :

```
<% @l2_mastertest.each_with_index do |row1, index1| %> 
   <% @l2_mastertest.each_with_index do |row2, index2| %> 
       <% if row2[0][ /(\d+\.\d+)/ ].to_s == row1[0].to_s %>      # LINE X
         ..................
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it gives me an error on line X saying : can't convert Regexp into Integer

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Using a regex as an index doesn't work, hence the error, but I can't make sense of what your trying to do so can't help any more than this.

Comment: row2[0] would be a string, something like "3.0.1.4"

Comment: There is no question in the post.

Comment: surely row2[0] is not a string that's why the error, you should first test it with debugger.

Comment: Looks like `row2[0]` should be a hash key, because `@l2_mastertest` is a hash following the `inject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I simulate what I think is going on with the data structures in your question, I get this:

```
@l2_mastertest = { '3.1.4' => 7, '1.2.3' => 8 }
 => {"3.1.4"=>7, "1.2.3"=>8}

@l2_mastertest.each_with_index { |row2,index| p row2,index }
["3.1.4", 7]
0
["1.2.3", 8]
1
```

So a structure like `row2[0][ /(\d+\.\d+)/ ]` is the same as e.g. `"3.1.4"[ /(\d+\.\d+)/ ]`

Edit: Removed my previous "answer", because actually `"3.1.4"[ /(\d+\.\d+)/ ] => "3.1"`, which is fine in Ruby (and I learned something today :-). Something else (possibly in code not shown) is making the @l2_mastertest hash not behave as expected.

Potentially this is a database/model issue, and as commenters have suggested, `row[0]` does not contain a string.

I would suggest instead that `SELECT * FROM builds;` is risky, since you are relying on database to return columns in particular order. You should change it to fetch the column data you need, in order e.g.

```
SELECT version, result, build_id FROM builds;
```

so that you are certain that later processing is working with the column that you think it is. Simply re-building or transferring the database could change the order that the RDBMS returns the columns in a `SELECT *` and make previously-working code break.